# Cant write to all textboxes in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to write a date that i picked up from datepicker in jquery-ui to all text boxes in my web app. For that i used a for loop like belows :

```
$(function() {
    $("#startdate_general").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
            updateAb(selected);
    }

    });
});


function updateAb(value){     
                for (i = 1; i < 626; i++) {
                    var startdate_param = 'startdate_' + i;

                    document.getElementById(startdate_param).value = value;

                    } 

}
```

It succeeded for the first 94 textboxes but the others were not written. I tried to do it partly 90 by 90. But nothing changed. I thought  that maybe its some kind of memory or cache problem. In bottomline, i could not figure it out. I would appreciate much any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you give a common classes to them and set the value at once without iterating.

Comment: You have 626 textboxes with all having the same value? Hm.. Anyway, give respectful inputs the same class and just use jquery `$('.date').val(value)`.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you checked the HTML, do all the elements exist with the given `id`?

Comment: What is the exact ID of the 95th (and further) textbox? Probably not the same as the 94th.

Comment: Yes some textboxes were missing. And Arvind came up with solution as following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply use starts with selector:

```
function updateAb(value){     
    $('input[type=text][id^=startdate_]').val(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even you can do this in your onSelect callback:

```
onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
      //updateAb(selected);
     $('[id^="startdate"]').val(selected);
}
```